# Template parameter deduction problem with C++ concepts and `std::is_same`

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts

If I try to write a function that is restricted by a concept to either `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` with `Key` keys and `Element` elements it fails to deduce the `Key` type in the following piece of code.

```cpp
template<typename A, typename B>
concept is_same_as = std::is_same<A, B>::value;

template<typename T, typename Key, typename Element>
concept map_type_of =
    is_same_as<T, std::map<Key, Element>> ||
    is_same_as<T, std::unordered_map<Key, Element>>;

template <typename T, typename Key, typename Element>
requires map_type_of<T,Key,Element>
inline std::list<Key> map_extract_keys(T const& a) {
    std::list<Key> output;
    for (auto const& element : a) {
        output.push_back(element.first);
    }
    return output;
}

std::map<std::string, int> map_example;

auto keys = map_extract_keys(map_example);
```

The actual error it gives:

```
candidate: ‘template<class T, class Key, class Element>  requires  map_type_of<T, Key, Element> std::__cxx11::list<Key> map_extract_keys(const T&)’
inline std::list<Key> map_extract_keys(T const& a) {

note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘Key’
```

Is there any way to allow that automatic deduction?

Comment: `template <typename T, typename Key, typename Element> inline std::list<Key> map_extract_keys(T const& a)` How exactly do you want this piece of code to know what a `Key` of `T` is?

Comment: Sadly C++ doesn't allow structured bindings with concrete types, thus there is no way to specify it in the `for` loop: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0480r1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `map_type_of` concept doesn't help you over a simpler concept

```
template<typename T>
concept is_map = std::ranges::range<T> 
              && std::semiregular<typename T::key_type> 
              && std::semiregular<typename T::mapped_type>;

template <typename T>
requires is_map<T>
inline std::list<typename T::key_type> map_extract_keys(T const& a) {
    std::list<typename T::key_type> output;
    for (auto const& [key, value] : a) {
        output.push_back(key);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Which, as a bonus, allows things like `boost::bimap<...>::left_map` etc

Answer (score 0):

With minimal changes to your code I guess you could do:

```
template <template <typename, typename> class T, typename K, typename E>
requires map_type_of<T<K,E>, K, E>
inline auto map_extract_keys(T<K,E> const& a) {
    std::list<K> output;
    for (auto const& element : a) {
        output.push_back(element.first);
    }
    return output;
}
```